# There is no output of information from the database on the client

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason, the client does not display information from the database. I do not know what the problem is anymore.I use Rails Api, Angular, and the Sqlite3 database.The application was deployed on the Nginx web server using puma and capistrano.

Maybe I missed something **posts_controller.rb**:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    render json: @posts
  end

  def show
    render json: @post
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
    else
      render json: @post.erros, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
  end

  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit!
    end
end
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev describe in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest checking your Angular app, maybe something is crashing on the JS side. Maybe making sure Rails is returning data by running a REST request using a chrome REST extension or something.

Make sure you're running the same Rails environment, and the database (if you're on development somewhere, and production somewhere else, databases will differ.

You can always go to rails console and make sure Post.all returns content. Your controller seems correct.

Comment: Thanks, I really had a problem with the script